# R: Warning when subsetting dataframe with a factor, but not with a character

Tags: r, subset, factors

Let's start with some data:

```
set.seed(0)
data <- data.frame('Group' = rep(c('Control', 'Disease'), 10),
                   'SV_mL' = rnorm(20),
                   'CO_L' = rnorm(20))
```

Now let's create a factor out of the two variables of interest, `SV_mL` and `CO_L`.

```
var <- as.factor(colnames(data)[colnames(data) != 'Group'])
```

Subsetting based on the `SV_mL` works whether I first convert it to a character or not:

```
mean(data[data$Group == 'Control',var[1]]) # 0.2077689
mean(data[data$Group == 'Control',as.character(var[1])]) # 0.2077689
```

But subsetting based on `CO_L` only works if I first convert it to a character:

```
mean(data[data$Group == 'Control',var[2]]) # NA
mean(data[data$Group == 'Control',as.character(var[2])]) # 0.194133
```

In the line that returns `NA`, I get the following warning:

```
Warning message: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I understand that I can avoid the problem by converting factors to characters before using them to subset a dataframe.  However, I'd like to understand why this is happening, and especially why it happens for one factor but not for another.

**A warning to those who come across this post.**

Thanks to the answer below, I now know that when you attempt to subset a dataframe based on a factor, it uses the numeric representation of that factor.  In this case, the numeric representation of `SV_mL` was 2 and of `CO_L` was 1 (based on the default alphabetical ordering).  It so happened that the first column of my dataframe was a factor--so I got an error.  The second column happened to be `SV_mL`, so I (quote unquote) "luckily" got the right answer.

Let's say this had been setup differently.

```
set.seed(0)
data <- data.frame('Group' = rep(c('Control', 'Disease'), 10),
                   'X' = rnorm(20),
                   'SV_mL' = rnorm(20),
                   'CO_L' = rnorm(20))

var <- as.factor(colnames(data)[colnames(data) != 'Group'])
```

In this case, `X` is the first factor, but its numeric representation is `3`.  Therefore, subsetting based on the factor representation, I would get the mean *of the wrong column*.

```
mean(data[data$Group == 'Control',var[1]]) # 0.194133
mean(data[data$Group == 'Control','X']) # 0.2077689
```

Dearie dearie me--we must be careful, mustn't we.

Comment: It looks like when you just use `var[1]` and `var[2]` it's actually referring to the numeric representation of those factors (2 and 1, respectively, for your example). See, for example, the result of `as.numeric(var)`, `data[, var[1]]`, and `data[, var[2]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that when you do not convert the factors to character they are treated as numeric in the subsetting.

```
var
[1] SV_mL CO_L
as.numeric(var)
[1] 2 1
```

Hence, SV_mL is considered '2' and gives the second column as you intended, but CO_L is considered '1' and returns the first column, which is the column `Group`. The mean of a vector of factors gives you the warning you see and returns NA.

```
mean(data$Group)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(data$Group) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: So in this case it just happened to be that `as.numeric(var[1])` was equal to `2`, and that `SV_mL` was the second column.  I could just as easily have gotten the mean of the WRONG column if I had set it up differently.  Terrifying.

Comment: @PyNewb, see `?"["` and `?"[<-.data.frame"` for more details on the i and j here. You can also look through the code at `[<-.data.frame`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto--much appreciated, will look those up.

Comment: @PyNewb, yes, you were lucky in the first case and unlucky in the second. But that is better as you could noticed the flaw. The assigned numbers is the ordering of the factor levels. Check `levels(var)`.